# PHP - can't get associative array's structure right

Tags: php, arrays, curl, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I try to send a request to an API (mailchimp) using cURL. It works with GET, however, I have problems converting the GET-URl into a proper associative PHP array to send via POST. *EDIT* Because as MarcB commented, GET requests have some negative sides, like a lenght limit, etc.

*Please note that I replaced the values of the variables with asteriks (**).
This is the working GET-parameter:

```
https://us3.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/ecomm/order-add.json?apikey=***
&order[id]=***
&order[campaign_id]=***
&order[email_id]=***
&order[total]=***
&order[store_id]=***
&order[items][0][product_id]=***
&order[items][0][category_id]=***
&order[items][0][category_name]=***
&order[items][1][product_id]=***
&order[items][1][category_id]=***
&order[items][1][category_name]=***
...
```

This is the PHP array for the POST request:

```
Array
(
    [apikey] => ***
    [order] => Array
        (
            [id] => ***
            [campaign_id] => ***
            [email_id] => ***
            [total] => ***
            [order_date] => ***
            [shipping] => ***
            [tax] => ***
            [store_id] => ***
            [store_name] => ***
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [product_id] => ***
                            [category_id] => ***
                            [category_name] => ***
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [product_id] => ***
                            [category_id] => ***
                            [category_name] => ***
                        )

                    ...

                )

        )

)
```

Response is:

```
Validation error: {\"order\":\"Please enter a struct\\\/associative array\"}
```

Any idea, what I am missing here? Isn't the structure here the same?

--
*UPDATE*:

This is the curl code:

```
function httpPost($url,$params)
{
  $postData = '';
   //create name value pairs seperated by &
   foreach($params as $k => $v) 
   { 
      $postData .= $k . '='.$v.'&'; 
   }
   rtrim($postData, '&');

    $ch = curl_init();  

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($postData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);    

    $output=curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    curl_close($ch);
    return array($output, $httpCode);

}

print_r( httpPost( $mc_api_url, $curl_data ) );
```

Comment: That's a pretty dang long query string. That much data should go via post, not a GET query. query strings are length limited for a reason, and yours might be getting truncated somewhere.

Comment: Hi @MarcB, yes thank you, you are right about that. That's why I want to do it via POST and not GET. The GET was just trying out if it works, but now I get this error when using POST and cannot see why?

Comment: well, that validation error looks like JSON. does the mailchimp API expect json? are you doing a proper json_encode() if that's the case?

Comment: No, it's not only with json, unfortunately. :(

Comment: can you show you code that is generating the cURL POST request? If you have already generated a query string for GET there is no reason whatsoever you shouldn't be able to simple use that same query string for POST.  The only question is does the target server expect different request formats for GET vs. POST

Comment: thank you @MikeBrant, I updated the question and added the curl code part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK for starters, you should not be manually building a query string.  You should either simply pass your associative array to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` or build the query string using something like `http_build_query()` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

Second, you should use a value of `true` for your `CURLOPT_POST` field.

Of course this is all assuming that API is expecting an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` POST request.  My guess is that this may not be the case, as your response seem like it is in JSON.

A brief glance of the MailChimp API documentation at http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/

Notes this:

> Request data is passed to the API by POSTing JSON objects to the API endpoints with the appropriate parameters.

If you are actually using this API version, then my guess is you need to do be forming JSON objects in the expected format nd using `application/json` as ContentType header.

If it helps, I have a very lightweight cURL-based REST client that you are welcome to use to more easily interact with RESTful services.  Check it out here: https://github.com/mikecbrant/php-rest-client

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and got it to work by adding a few extra conditions to my curl call. Try  adding these and see if it works:

```
$data = json_encode($data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```